# Send emails using Google App Engine in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, email

Is there any step by step tutorial to send emails using google app engine?
I found one gem https://github.com/maccman/remail 
But it is 4 year old gem and not sure whether it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see very much value in this as AppEngine is not very good nor cheap platform to send emails from.

You get [100 free emails per day](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Mail) and all senders need to be Google Apps accounts. If you need more than that then you need a billable app + special requests to increase quota. The price is 1 USD per 10k emails, which is on par with other SMTP providers.

There are a lot of email sending services with direct HTTP APIs and/or Rails gems: [Amazon SES](https://github.com/drewblas/aws-ses), [Sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/rubyonrails.html), [Postmark](https://github.com/wildbit/postmark-rails), etc..